# Sort one array based on the order of a separate array, when some items are missing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that stores a prefered order, and a larger array that I need to sort:

```js
const months = ['March', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec'];
const prefOrder = ['Feb', 'March']
months.sort((a, b) => (prefOrder.indexOf(a) - prefOrder.indexOf(b)));
// desired output: ['Feb', 'March', 'Dec', 'Jan']
// or: ['Feb', 'March', 'Jan', 'Dec' ]
console.log(months);
```

However, when two items being compared are not in the list (i.e. `(prefOrder.indexOf(a) - prefOrder.indexOf(b))` gives `(-1) - (-1) = 0)`) rather than them being at the end, they end up at the start... even though if you `a` not in the prefered order list, and `b` in the list, you'd get `(-1) - positive = negative` so `a` should be sorted after `b`.

How can I get use the preferred order list to put unlisted item at the end?

Comment: You'll have to check whether the month is in the prefOrder and return 0, and otherwise return the weight value of the month in comparison to the other.

Comment: why is `'Dec'` before `'Jan'`?

Comment: @NinaScholz it doesn't matter so long as it's stable. I was using string comparison initially when I wrote it out but I realised that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add one for getting a falsy value for unknown values and take a large value instead to move this items to the end of the known items.

```js
const
    months = ['March', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec'],
    prefOrder = ['Feb', 'March'];

months.sort((a, b) =>
    (prefOrder.indexOf(a) + 1 || Number.MAX_VALUE) -
    (prefOrder.indexOf(b) + 1 || Number.MAX_VALUE)
);

console.log(months);
```

Instead of using an array, take an object with wanted order and move unknown items to the end with a large default value.

```js
const
    months = ['March', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec'],
    order = { Feb: 1, March: 2 };

months.sort((a, b) =>
    (order[a] || Number.MAX_VALUE) -
    (order[b] || Number.MAX_VALUE)
);

console.log(months);
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do that this way...

```js
const
  months    = ['March', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Dec']
, prefOrder = ['Feb', 'March']
  ;

months.sort((a, b) =>
  { 
  if (!prefOrder.includes(a)) return +1
  if (!prefOrder.includes(b)) return -1
  return (prefOrder.indexOf(a) - prefOrder.indexOf(b))  
  })

console.log( JSON.stringify( months ))
```